# Determining if a html request comes from inside the office using PHP

Tags: php, webserver, httprequest

I am wondering about a certain server setup.

Lets say I have a web server running on my local network, which is accessible using an url such as www.example.com from within and also outside the network.

I would like my PHP website to be able to determine if a request comes from within the internal LAN or from the outside. I doubt that this will be possible using the IP address as the request will look as if it is coming from a public IP address, and not the internal one 192.168.x.x. Also the public IP might change from time to time.

Would this be possible, and how could i achieve this in PHP?

Comment: If the server is inside the network, any requests from inside the network will be from a LAN IP address. Just try echoing `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and you will see.

Comment: @dave: not necessarily. if example.com resolves to the outside IP, the internal request may be roundtripped out the front door and appear 'external', regardless.

Comment: This question isn't really related to PHP – that would be an implementation detail. As I understood the question, the OP asks, how to identify a client without using the IP. Is that right?

Comment: @MarcB (damn it, you were too quick for my comment edit) ...in which case, all internal requests will appear to be from you own public IP - so if all you are trying to is determine internal or external, you can safely use this. Of course if you want to determine *which* LAN client is the origin, you're a bit stuck. Although you could force LAN clients to use IE and use NTLM auth if you are using a Windows domain, but that is nasty nasty.

Comment: That is exactly my question. example.com will resolve to the outside IP and thus it will appear as a public IP. I do not need to know which client specifically made the request, just if it comes from within the internal network or not.

Comment: Why not then just resolve to the internal IP, it should save you some overhead.

Comment: @MichaelFrey Then you can safely assume that if the originating IP is your own public IP address, it is an internal request. The other (horrible) way to do it would be hard-code the DNS name into the hosts file on all the internal machines and point it at the server's LAN address. Then it will actually be the LAN IP.

Comment: @daverandom This is actually an idea, but will not work in this case. i have tablets, which connect over the wifi while in the office, but using mobile networks (public ip) while out of office.

Comment: @MichaelFrey well that is an entirely different thing, which requires an entirely different approach really...

Comment: @MichaelFrey When said tablets are outside the office, do you want to treat them as external? How would you handle internal vs. external differently in your application?

Comment: @daverandom Yes they should be handled as external while outside the office, and internal while inside the office.

Comment: Then I think comparing against your own public IP would be the safest way. See my second comment and @helmus' answer.

Comment: also, if you can guarantee that the tablets will work on wifi wile inside the office, you don't need to change anything.

Comment: @MichaelFrey `$host = explode(':', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']); if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == gethostbyname($host[0])) { echo 'Internal'; } else { echo 'External'; }` - works, I have just tested it. The `explode()` is there because `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` may also contain a port number, which will break the DNS lookup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your requests comes from inside the lan then the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] will be from a private ip address group, if if comes from outside the lan it will not.
Unless you have a poorly configured internal network, but this will probably not be the case.

look here for the correct address groups
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network

If your internal dns server resolves example.com to the public ip then the requests will appear to come from the public ip as well, so if this is the case you also know that the request came from inside.

Comment: So since there is only one public IP address for the entire network i can compare the request ip to the servers public ip. But how would I check the server's public ip address?

Comment: ether hard code it or use http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php, possibly in combination with the host header

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know what the external NAT IP range is for your office, you should be able to do this easily be accessing the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] value.